# java.lang.InterruptedException with Tinkerpop 3.7.1

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

So I have a multithreaded Java service which is reading events off a queue and writing the objects to a Tinkerpop graph instance.   It can crank along for quite sometime, but will eventually die with an InterruptedException.    I've tried adding a synchronize to my consume function which did seem to make it last a little longer, but it eventually died again with the same stack trace:

```
ingestion  | 08:48:44.450 [partition-pump-1-7] WARN  a.i.g.i.TinkerpopGraphDriver - Caught Tinkerpop error on submit.  Trying one more time.
ingestion  | java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException
ingestion  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:265)
ingestion  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:230)
ingestion  |    at ambientsecurity.identity.gremlin.impl.TinkerpopGraphDriver.consume(TinkerpopGraphDriver.java:79)
...

ingestion  | Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
ingestion  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:385)
ingestion  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2005)
ingestion  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:261)
ingestion  |    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Any thoughts?

Should note this code runs happily against Azure Cosmos, but I'm trying to get a local docker solution to work before I make Microsoft too rich.